# Interesting SQL query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like so (yes structure sucks, can't change it):

```
Id |  line | Status|TimeStamp |  AssociationID
1  |   A   | close | 10:30 am |  f2da3
2  |   A   | ack   | 10:15 am |  f2da3
3  |   A   | open  | 10:00 am |  f2da3
4  |   A   | close | 09:10 am |  j7s9d
5  |   A   | ack   | 08:45 am |  j7s9d
6  |   A   | open  | 08:00 am |  j7s9d
```

Note: TimeStamp is datetime datatype.

I need a SQL query which will give me the elapsed time (in minutes) between 'open' to 'close' per `AssociationID.`

So output table would look like:

```
AssociationID | OpenToCloseTime
   f2da3      |    30
   j7s9d      |    70
```

What would the SQL query look like? I am extremely out of my element here and any help is appreciated!

Comment: You tagged your question with three different DBMS: `mysql`, `sql-server` and `sqlite`. Which one are you using?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions only with the appropriate database.  What is the data type of TimeStamp?

Comment: Please be specific with regards to DBMS choice.

Comment: @TangoAlee . . . To phrase it differently, it is unlikely that you will get a good answer to this question without a reasonable tag for the database.  People who would be inclined to answer will probably not answer when the question is so confused about the target system.

Comment: And this is interesting?

Comment: I apologize - I didn't know DBMS made a difference to the SQL statement. I'm using Sql-Server 2008. I fixed the flags.

@GordonLinoff - the datatype of the TimeStamp is DateTime.

Comment: With a question like this, it would normally be a great idea to also state the data type in each column. Although you do reference it in a comment here, for next time, pop it into the question to avoid confusion :)

Comment: I've fixed the question per the requests. Please reopen this so it's not marked 'on hold'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? This would work provided associationId,Status is unique.

```
WITH A AS
(
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE status = 'Close' 
)
,B as
(
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE Status = 'Open'
)
SELECT
    A.AssociationID,
    DATEDIFF(minute,A.TimeStamp,B.TimeStamp) 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON
A.AssociationID = B.AssociationId
```

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thank you Johnny